# Given $f(x)=2x-6$ and $g(x)=x+3$, sketch the graph of $f(x), g(x), (f\circ g)(x)$, and $(g\circ f)(x)$

Tags: graphing-functions, function-and-relation-composition

This is what I got:

Blue: $g(x)$

Red: $f(x)$

Yellow: $(g\circ f)(x)$

Green: $(f\circ g)(x)$

[image]

Comment: what is the meaning of your $*$?Composition or product?

Comment: Product, sorry.

Comment: @DfasdSadsadasd But  you have done the composition of the functions

Comment: If $*$ was composition it would be correct, but as product the last two are wrong.

Comment: Well product is commutative, so that immediately throws up a flag that something's amiss.

Comment: My bad guys, I meant composition haha

Comment: Okay, all your graphs are correct.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct.

[image: page 1]

Blue line for f(x) = 2x - 6

Pink for g(x) = x + 3

Green for fog(x) = 2x

Yellow for gof(x) = 2x - 3

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is. I assume it is $f o g$ (where o is the composition operator).

The linear functions are easy to draw I assume. you put x=0 and find y value then you put y=0 and find the x value, then you draw the line.

For $f(x)=2x-6$

when $x=0$ you get $y=-6$. This gives you the first point on the line to be $(x,y)=(0,-6)$.

when $y-0$ you get $2x-6=0$ this gives $2x=6$ that is $x=3$ when $y=0$. You now have another point $(x,y)=(3,0)$.

A line is determined by 2 points. So you can draw a line segment between $(0,-6), (3,0)$.

The same process could be applied to draw any line equation.

For $y=x+3$
You follow the same procedure about to get the points $(0,3)$ and $(-3,0)$.

Now to draw the *composition* term $(f o g)$, you need to understand it. Please see reference 1 below.

In your case, $(f o g)$ = $f(g(x))=2(x+3)-6=2x$

$(g o f)$ is $g(f(x))$ = $(2x-6) + 3 =2x-3$

For the chart of all these functions see:[Desmos-Chart](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gebgf5zyoq)

Ref1:[Composition of functions](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/functions-composition.html)